# Tight fit div around an image

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I am working on trying to make a chat app and need chat bubbles to tightly fit around their content. It works alright for text, but when I have an image in the bubble it gets problematic. Here is the HTML that I am using

```
<div class="fromMe msgBubble">
    <img src="{{image.location}}" style="width:50%;">
    <br>
    <span class="msgDate">2011-01-26 01:52:16</span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

However, when I load the image I have a whole bunch of padding off to the side of the image, and the div doesn't tightly wrap around the image. It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXbLT.jpg

UPDATE: I posted a JS Fiddle with the code and CSS. 
https://jsfiddle.net/dw9aek2y/

How can I tight fit the chat bubble div around the picture?
Thanks!

Comment: check CSS if your image have property display: block; then you will have this problem

Comment: @ackerchez   you can use max-width in order to maintain width   https://jsfiddle.net/dw9aek2y/1/

Comment: @Adnan Akram that still does the same thing..just smaller.https://jsfiddle.net/dw9aek2y/2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove width and add max-width and every thing will be fine

```css
#messageBubbleArea {
    font: 14px Arial;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 99%;
}

.fromMe::before {
    border-bottom: 9px solid #0b93f6;
    border-right: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
}

*::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fromMe {
    background-color: #0b93f6;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right;
}

.fromThem, .fromMe {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="messageBubbleArea">
  <div class="fromMe msgBubble">Hey babe<br>
    <span class="msgDate">2011-01-26 00:09:30</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="fromMe msgBubble">
    <img style=" max-width:200px;" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/rainbow-clip-art-rainbow.gif"><br>
    <span class="msgDate">2011-01-26 01:52:16</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I see that. But what if I want to display the image as a thumbnail and not in full? Do I have to dynamically create a thumbnail version? Can't I just resize it?

Comment: @ackerchez you can resize it. decrease max-width as per your requirement